# how to start out with no results and get rid of all results on "blank" search for Sunspot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot

There are 2 issues I have when using Sunspot for a Search engine.

The 1st issue is I have a link that goes to `search/index` and when it does this is show all of the Products in my database which is what I don't want all. How do I make it so it shows no results and users have to use the search field?

The 2nd issue is when users type in a blank search `" "` it returns all of the products in the database when it should return `"No Search Results Found"`. How can get it to do this?

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = Product.search do
        fulltext params[:search]    
    end
    @products = @search.results
  end
end

resources :search, :only => [:index]

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  # Sunspot config
  searchable do
    text :name
  end
end

<%= form_tag search_path, :method => :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort of hit both issues with 1 fix.

```
# /app/controllers/search_controller.rb
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = []

    # If the search param with it's whitespace stripped off
    # actually has something left then search for it
    unless params[:search].nil? || params[:search].strip.empty?
        @search = Product.search do
            fulltext params[:search]    
        end
        @products = @search.results
    end

    @products
  end
end

# /app/views/search/index.haml
- if @products.empty? 
    Your search did not return any results.
- else
    # display the results or do whatever you want to do when something is actually found
```

Basically what I'm proposing is that you start SearchController#index by setting `@products` to an empty array.  If the search param is passed in we check it's stripped result (white space removed) and see if there's anything left.

If the user has searched a bunch of spaces, then `strip` will have reduced that to nothing and the search will not be run.

In the event the stripped version of the search param does actually have something in there (aka probably valid search text) then do the search and set `@products` to the set of results.

Finally, return `@products`.

In your view, you can then check the `@products` array to see if it's empty or not.  If it's empty then either the user searched for whitespace (bogus) or their search didn't return anything... so you can take appropriate action based on that.

Comment: Strange, it doesn't recognize the method `strip`. I get the error `undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: I added a nil check `params[:search].nil?` can you try that?  I feel like this is a hack... so even if it ultimately works, i bet someone with more expertise knows a more correct way.

Comment: This did work. I will play around with it but this gets me on the right track, thank you.

Comment: can't you just do params[:search].blank?